# MySQL SELECT Query assumes 1623x=1623 is True

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

Does anyone know why this query is returning results when it shouldn't? The code in the query has an extra x but the code in the database doesn't have.

```
SELECT * FROM `otp` WHERE `code`= '1623x' AND `userid`='4' AND `status`='1'
```

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Morgs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE `code`= '1623x'
```

I strongly suspect that `code` is a numeric column.

If so: to evaluate the condition, MySQL has to compare a number to a string. What it does is coerce the string to a number, and then perform numeric comparison. It turns out that string `'1623x'` translates to number `1623`, so the condition is fullfilled.

If, for example, the string had been `'x1623'`, it would have been converted to `0` (because it does not start with a digit), and you wouldn't have received any result.

In a nutshell: don't compare values of different datatypes. Each database has it own understanding on what should happen in this case, which might, or might not feel intuitive to you.

Comment: @Morgs: welcome. Note that this also applies to the other conditions in the `where` clause, since `user_id` and `status` are also probably integer columns. So: `where code = 1623 AND userid = 4 AND status = 1` .

Comment: "don't do that" isn't a very appealing solution.  it means when you are using user input you have to go to extra work in the presumably rare case of incorrect input to verify that it is of the correct type.  better to just do that as part of the query IMO

Comment: @ysth I interpret GMB's comment just as a general warning to not even end up in a situation where strings are being compared against integers.  Assuming this query be generated by something like a PHP script, then the OP should ensure that only integers are used on the RHS of the comparison.

Comment: @GMB true, I've a generic `db_helper` that adds '' to every column value and at this point it is not possible for me to know the column type in the db. But I will have to re-invent the wheel somehow, as I assume I am giving the database extra work casting/parsing the values..

Comment: @Morgs If I understand you correctly, adding '' to every column value can just disable your indexing - you really don't want to do that

Comment: @ysth I will have to rewrite my queries to overcome this. Thanks everyone for the helpful input

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is due to MySQL's particular *casting* rules.  When you try to compare the string literal `'1623x'` to the integer `1623`, MySQL has to do something to first bring the LHS and RHS to the same type.  The only way to do that is to cast `'1623x'` to an integer.  The casting rules are such that if the string starts with an integer, then MySQL will retain as many digits are available.  In this case, `'1623x'` becomes the integer `1623`, and so the LHS and RHS become true.

To be clear, here is the query which is evaluating to yield the unexpected record:

```
SELECT *
FROM otp
WHERE 1623 = 1623 AND userid = 4 AND status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses the type of the right operand to cast the left operand.  If you have an integer type column `code` and you say `code = '123abc'`, it becomes equivalent to `code = 123` (with a warning).  If you want to prevent that (and also things like `code = '00123'` or `code = '123.0'`) from finding 123, add an additional where condition to also do a string comparison:

```
and code='123abc' and concat(code)='123abc'
```

(or use cast instead of concat).  I suggest an additional comparison rather than just replacing the existing one so that code can still be used for index lookups.